# PHP - Iterate through folders and display HTML contents

Tags: php, wordpress, iteration, loops

I'm currently trying to develop a method to get a overview of all my different web templates I've created and (legally) downloaded over the years. I thought about displaying them like [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) is previewing its templates with a small preview window, displaying the concrete file with styles and everything.

How do I divide them into rows and columns and create [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) modal window open on preview and pagination and so on?

I believe I can manage, but it is the concept itself about iterating over several folders and then finding all `index.htm` and `index.html` pages and displaying them.

I've not worked very much with directories in PHP and the only references and code stumps I've found so far is just to list all the files in a certain directory like, what it contains.

Is there a script, a function, snippet or just some information to create such a (probably simple) preview function?

Comment: If you're able to find code samples to iterate over a directory and lists its contents it sounds to me like the only piece you're missing is filtering it to just HTML files. Where is it you are stuck exactly?

Comment: [`glob('*.html')`](http://php.net/glob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glob('*.html')` will work if they're all in one directory.

If you want to walk a file tree -- checking everything in the current directory and in subdirectories and subdirectories of subdirectories (etc) -- then you have a couple of options.

One would be to use the unix `find` command with one of the methods of PHP system invocation. Something like:

`find <search_root_dir> -name "*.html" -print`

will get you output that looks something like

```
search_root_dir/blah.html
search_root_dir/foo.html
search_root_dir/subdir/baz.html
search_root_dir/subdir/bah.html
...
```

Another thing you could do is write a recursive function that uses `chdir` and `readdir` or maybe `scandir`, something like:

```
function dir_walk($start_dir,$func) {
    $entries = scandir($start_dir);
    foreach($entries as $entry) {
        if($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
            /*skip these*/
        } else if(is_dir($entry)) {
            dir_walk($start_dir.'/'.$entry,$func);
        } else $func($start_dir.'/'.$entry);
    }
}
```

Then, write another function:

```
$html_files = array();
function record_html_files($filename) {
   global $html_files;
   if(strpos($filename,'*.html') === (strlen($filename) - 6))
     $html_files[] = $filename;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
dir_walk('/path/to/search/root','record_html_files');
```

Or, write dir_walk so it accepts an object with a method call you can make inside. There's some variations possible here.